# Biometric Attendance Device with Direct Real Time Nodejs VPS Server Connectivity

Tags: node.js, sdk, real-time, fingerprint, biometrics

I am planning to develop a custom, **real-time attendance** system using Node.js and I'm looking for recommendations on both the architecture and biometric devices that can integrate smoothly with a Node.js express environment. The key requirement is for the biometric device to **directly connect to a Node.js VPS server** and reliably transmit attendance data in real-time or near-real-time.

Here are the specific areas where I need advice:

1. Could you recommend biometric devices (preferably fingerprint scanners) that **can directly connect to a VPS server** and are known for their compatibility with Node.js, either through official SDKs or well-supported community libraries? The goal is to **minimize local processing** and have the device send attendance data directly to the server
2. Are there devices with native functionality for this purpose, or would a custom solution be required to facilitate such connectivity?

I'm looking for insights, experiences, or recommendations on suitable architectures, biometric devices, and Node.js integration strategies for this kind of system.